# how to capture the recaptcha response in ui

Tags: ember.js

I have installed the `ember-g-recaptcha` addon in my ember app using `ember install ember-g-recaptcha`. I'm able to see the recaptcha in the UI. But how do I check whether that box is checked or not. If it's not checked my form should not submit and should display an error message.

I want to display this error message when the response is empty. I have written this in my controllers:

```
 onCaptchaExpired() { 
   $("#message").show();
   $("#message").css("color", "red");
   $("#message").html("Recaptcha response cannot be empty.");
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you *really* should rely on `ember` to manage the DOM, and don't do it manually with `jQuery`.

A simple solution could be to just toggle a boolean when the `g-recaptcha` component fires the actions:

*template:*

```
{{g-recaptcha onSuccess=(action "onCaptchaResolved") onExpired=(action "onCaptchaExpired")}}
{{captchaError}}

<button disabled={{isInvalid}} />
```

*component:*

```
Ember.Component.extend({
    isInvalid: true,
    captchaError: null,
    actions: {
        onCaptchaResolved(captchaResult) {
            this.set('isInvalid', false);
        },
        onExpired() {
            this.set('isInvalid', true);
            this.set('captchaError', 'Recaptcha response cannot be empty.')
        }
    }
})
```

This should give you an idea how you could do this.